# Don't understand why my question is closed

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions, reopen-closed, opinion-based

I have a question about my Stack Overflow post: [Is reverse proxy in front of Node reasonable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73676095/is-reverse-proxy-in-front-of-node-reasonable)

I don't understand why my question is closed as "opinion-based". I agree that it's somewhat abstract, but why is it opinion-based? There are objective reasons why you'd like to place a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy). To balance load, for example. I am sure there are more. I'd like to get more reasons from more experienced folks.

I read tutorials on [React](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/React_(JavaScript_library)), [Next.js](https://nextjs.org/), etc. deployments and all of them are placing [Nginx](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nginx) in front of [Node.js](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Node.js) as a reverse proxy. I feel that I don't *fully* understand why it is so. That's why I asked this question.

Anyway, if this question is bad, how can I improve it? I tried to edit, but maybe it's still not good enough.

Comment: In which cases it's reasonable to place reverse proxy (Nginx / Apache) in front? **My opinion is that it's reasonable when ...**

Comment: Even if it's not opinion-based, it's still too broad and would be closed.

Comment: "if this question is bad" - a lot of confusion about Stack Overflow stems from wrong terminology being used. And even regulars frequently fall in that trap. Your question is not *bad*. It is off-topic. On a site which is more aimed towards discussion and/or tutoring, your question is just fine. But Stack Overflow is not such a site. Very much on purpose, it tries to fill the niche corner of the web that didn't exist yet. A knowledge base, filled with quality answers.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Define reasonable. Is my reasonable, the same as yours?

Looks like you're also looking for a list of things and questions that want an [unbounded list don't really do well](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/11/23/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/). So in that sense the question is also too broad as we could write a book about all the different reasons you might want to use a reverse proxy and how.

What you need to start from is a specific programming problem i.e. *I've written the following ReactJS application and it has this specific problem...* The answer to that question might end up being that you need to use a reverse proxy and the answerer might even show you how Nginx or Apache could be configured to be that solution.

Comment: I understand and agree with your point.
Could you please explain to me the difference between my question and, for example, this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770673/using-node-js-only-vs-using-node-js-with-apache-nginx
It uses particular terms, but it's still too broad and old. No?

Comment: That question was written in 2013 i.e. its nearly 10 years old, the site was still working out what a good question was back then so old upvoted questions aren't always the same as good questions.

Comment: *"Is my reasonable, the same as yours?"* Sure, as long as you're a reasonable person!

Comment: @CodyGray I'm sure as a Stack Overflow moderator your idea of reasonable is challenged every couple of minutes by someone or other's flag.

Answer (score 9):

I'll be a bit more direct than [Robert was with his answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/420324/1079354).

The crux of your question states:

> My goal is to understand when we need Node + reverse proxy, when just Node. So, I'll be greatful for in-depth answers.

So basically you want to know circumstances in which it makes sense to use a reverse proxy and when it doesn't make sense to use a reverse proxy.

I hate to say it like this, but that's not an exact science. Everyone's use case will be different and everyone's deployment strategy will vary.  There may be official advice from Node themselves that would be advised to follow, or you may have the capacity to accept risk and not follow that guidance.

In essence, this is opinion-based because *you're directly asking for an opinion* on how to deploy a Node application.

To the part about fixing it - I don't think there is a way to fix this specific question, since it's so specialized.  I can't see a suitable transformation of this question into something more on-topic without it being an entirely different question, either focused explicitly on deploying a Node app without a reverse proxy, or deploying it with a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 1):

> My goal is to understand when we need Node + reverse proxy, when just Node. So, I'll be [grateful] for in-depth answers.

The objective phrasing of a question, then, is something like "*what is accomplished* by putting a reverse proxy in front of a Node server?", or perhaps "*what are the consequences of not* using a reverse proxy?" Or perhaps "what should I consider when deciding whether to add a reverse proxy?"

But, yes, that probably still "needs more focus". Unless, of course, you already have an answer and have designed the question to accomodate a coherent, well-written answer.